# Kubernetes deployment not scaling down even though usage is below threshold

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I’m having a hard time understanding what’s going on with my horizontal pod autoscaler.

I’m trying to scale up my deployment if the memory or cpu usage goes above 80%.

Here’s my HPA template:

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 80
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 80
```

The thing is, it’s been sitting at 3 replicas for days even though the usage is below 80% and I don’t understand why.

```
$ kubectl get hpa --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE        NAME             REFERENCE                  TARGETS            MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
my-ns            my-hpa           Deployment/my-deployment   61%/80%, 14%/80%   2         10        3          2d15h
```

Here’s the output of the top command:

```
$ kubectl top pods

NAME                             CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
my-deployment-86874588cc-chvxq   3m           146Mi           
my-deployment-86874588cc-gkbg9   5m           149Mi           
my-deployment-86874588cc-nwpll   7m           149Mi
```

Each pod consumes approximately 60% of their requested memory (So they are below the 80% target):

```yaml
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "256Mi"
    cpu: "100m"
  limits:
    memory: "512Mi"
    cpu: "200m"
```

Here's my deployment:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: ...
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /liveness
              port: 3000
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /readiness
              port: 3000
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
```

I manually scale down to 2 replicas and it goes back up to 3 right away for no reason:

```
Normal   SuccessfulRescale             28s (x4 over 66m)    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 3; reason:
```

Anyone have any idea what’s going on?

Comment: Can you describe your Deployment? Any chance that there are 3 replicas set there manually?

Comment: Probably because `ceil(3 * (60/80))` is `3`, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/.

Comment: @TonyStark I manually scaled down to 2 replicas and it went back up to 3. That's weird because `ceil(2 * (60/80))` is `2`

Comment: Can you give us more info (export the "deployment" RD as yaml for example) like @UroshT. says?

Comment: @TonyStark I updated my question

Comment: Ugh, for the calculation real memory values should probably be taken and not percentage, my bad. Now it kinda looks like a bug. Anything in the events/logs?

Comment: What is the kubernetes version are you using ?Your cluster is bare metal or in the cloud?

Comment: I'm using 1.16.6 in the cloud

Comment: @EtienneMartin are you using self-managed cluster in the cloud, or as a service like EKS, GKE or AKS?

Comment: @KoopaKiller As a service

Comment: I've tested in my lab and didn't gget the same result. What's is your could provider? Could you provide the image you are using, or other with the smae behavior ?

Comment: I got a case where i had the side car looping on log errors that's why it didn't scale down..

Answer (score 5):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details

As per your current numbers, It will never scale down unless your memory usage goes down to half of the desired percentage.

i.e the current utilization of both cpu and memory should go to 40%(in your case) or below

as per the below formula

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
                = ceil[3 * (61/80)]
                = ceil[3 * (0.7625)]
                = ceil[2.2875]
desiredReplicas = 3
```

you might be having doubt like your cpu is below 40% why it is not downscaling.. but hpa will not work in that way.. it will always look for larger number.

Comment: took me like 3 minutes to figure out `ceil` thing, but after I figured out its `ceiling` instantly understood your point. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because like you i was using 2 metrics **CPU and Memory**. The memory resource is never quickly released by the application as the CPU does. **Once I removed the memory resource the pods scaled down when the utilization was less.**