# HPA not scaling down

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

I hope you can shed some light on this.

I am facing the same issue as described here: [Kubernetes deployment not scaling down even though usage is below threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959284/kubernetes-deployment-not-scaling-down-even-though-usage-is-below-threshold)

My configuration is almost identical.

I have checked the hpa algorithm, but I cannot find an explanation for the fact that I am having only one replica of my-app3.
Any hints?

```
kubectl get hpa -A 

NAMESPACE            NAME        REFERENCE              TARGETS            MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
my-ns1               my-app1     Deployment/my-app1     49%/75%, 2%/75%    1         10        2          20h
my-ns2               my-app2     Deployment/my-app2     50%/75%, 10%/75%   1         10        2          22h
my-ns2               my-app3     Deployment/my-app3     47%/75%, 10%/75%   1         10        1          22h
```

```
kubectl top po -A

NAMESPACE             NAME                                                     CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)              
my-ns1                pod-app1-8d694bc8f-mkbrh                                 1m           76Mi            
my-ns1                pod-app1-8d694bc8f-qmlnw                                 1m           72Mi            
my-ns2                pod-app2-59d895d96d-86fgm                                1m           77Mi            
my-ns2                pod-app2-59d895d96d-zr67g                                1m           73Mi            
my-ns2                pod-app3-6f8cbb68bf-vdhsd                                1m           47Mi
```

Comment: why would you have more? it sits at 1m CPU? also, not related to AKS at all. also read the answer in the linked thread

Comment: What I was finding weird was that the currentMetricValue/desiredMetricValue was almost the same for all HPAs, but this one remained at 1.
Indeed according to the formula there is no need to scale out the pods..

Comment: @Catalin as I see you have found the reason why your `HPA` is not scaling up/down your `Deployments`. As you found the reason please provide an answer to your question to help the community with similar issues. PS: `my-app3` would scale to 2 replicas when the target value would be above 75%. `my-app2` would scale to 1 replica when the target value would be less than 37,5%.

Answer (score 4):

Posting this answer as it could be beneficiary for the community members on why exactly `Horizontal Pod Autoscaler` decided **not** to scale the amount of replicas in this particular setup.

The formula for amount of replicas workload will have is:

> desiredReplicas = ceil[**currentReplicas** * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]

Following on the describe of `HPA`:

```sh
NAMESPACE            NAME        REFERENCE              TARGETS            MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
my-ns1               my-app1     Deployment/my-app1     49%/75%, 2%/75%    1         10        2          20h
my-ns2               my-app2     Deployment/my-app2     50%/75%, 10%/75%   1         10        2          22h
my-ns2               my-app3     Deployment/my-app3     47%/75%, 10%/75%   1         10        1          22h
```

`HPA` decides on the amount of replicas on the premise of their **current amount**.

**A side note**: In the setup that uses multiple metrics (for example `CPU` and `RAM`) it will use the higher metric and act accordingly.

Also please consider that [downscaling has a cooldown](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay).

---

#### Calculation on each of the `Deployments`

> `ceil[]` - round a number up:
>
> - ceil(4,55) = 5
> - ceil(4,01) = 5

`app1`:

- `Replicas` = ceil[`2` * (`49` / `75`)]
- `Replicas` = ceil[`2` * `0,6533..`]
- `Replicas` = ceil[`1,3066..`]
- `Replicas` = **`2`**

This example shows that there will be no changes to be amount of replicas.

Amount of replicas would go:

- **Up** when the `currentMetricValue` (`49`) would exceed the `desiredMetricValue` (`75`)
- **Down** when the `currentMetricValue` (`49`) would be **less than half** of the `desiredMetricValue` (`75`)

`app2` is in the same situation as `app1` so it can be skipped

`app3`:

- `Replicas` = ceil[`1` * (`49` / `75`)]
- `Replicas` = ceil[`1` * `0,6266..`]
- `Replicas` = ceil[`0,6266..`]
- `Replicas` = **`1`**

This example also shows that there will be no changes to be amount of replicas.

Amount of replicas would go:

- **Up** when the `currentMetricValue` (`47`) would exceed the `desiredMetricValue` (`75`)

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Run application: Horizontal pod autoscale](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)*

Answer (score 0):

Indeed from my research it seems that the HPA algorithm works in this way:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details

Do not know the reason why my-app3 was assigned one replica and the other two apps two replicas, but according to the algorithm it is not needed to scale out at this time.